# Clion says clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Tags: c++, clion

I recently downloaded Clion and ran into some problem. First I wrote one simple code (it works), then I created another C++ file and wrote another simple code. But now, when running either of these two codes, an error is thrown:

```
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

when I remove one of the codes, the other one starts working. I seem to have found a solution on stackoverflow and it says just do **Clean** and then **Build**, though I can't figure out how to do it. Will you help?

Comment: Why do you see only the last output line?

Comment: My crystal ball says you have two files in your project with a `main` function and the error is due to multiple definitions. Hard to tell without the complete error and the code in question.

Comment: Okay, here it is
duplicate symbol '_main' in:
    CMakeFiles/CodeForces.dir/4A.cpp.o
    CMakeFiles/CodeForces.dir/71A.cpp.o
ld: 1 duplicate symbol for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make[3]: *** [CodeForces] Error 1
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/CodeForces.dir/all] Error 2
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/CodeForces.dir/rule] Error 2
make: *** [CodeForces] Error 2

Comment: Retired ninja's crystal ball works again, you have two `main` functions in a suitable program, there can be only one

Comment: how to fix it??

Comment: Remove one of the main functions?

Comment: every time when I create a new C++ file I must do something like [[maybe_unused]] int main1{. . .} ?